# How can I control a empty JsonArray, if string is " [ ] "

Tags: java, android, json

my json string is

```
String RESPONSE = "  { "Table": [] }  ";
```

and I use

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(RESPONSE);
 JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");
```

Therefore, contacts = [] I mean empty.
**How can I control that array is empty.**
After this controller I use this command

```
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
```

Of course is not empty :)

Comment: What do you mean "Of course is not empty"?  Did you put something in it after your previous code where you obtained a clearly empty array?

Comment: if contacts is not empty continue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` function:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(RESPONSE);
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");
if(contacts.length() > 0 ) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
}
```

Comment: I've tried. Not working

Comment: what was happening, were you getting some error?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `isNull()` function.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(RESPONSE);
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");
if(!contacts.isNull(0)) {
   JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
}
```

Comment: No such function

Comment: Correct. Edited to show isNull.

Comment: No, Not working

Comment: contacts = " [ ] " ;

Comment: Have I miss understood the question? What do you mean by not working? are you saying contacts[0] is empty yet the if statement is still executing?

Comment: contacts has a string that is " [ ] ", but I want to assume empty

Comment: be careful Response is { "Table": [] }

Comment: Try checking if the array is not null and the length is greater than 0. Try: if(contacts != null && contacts.length() > 0)

Comment: I tried man. but not working

Comment: Works at this end, but maybe I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!